# Importing edited PDF's in Latex

Tags: pdf

I have some PDF files and I'm editing them in Foxit Reader. After editing I want to load those PDF files in Latex, but when I load files, it just includes the original PDF and the editing done on PDF is gone. Anybady have an idea how to fix it?

Regards

Comment: What happens if you open the edited PDF with another viewer?

Comment: It opens fine with edited stuff.

Comment: A trick I use in situations like this is to print the edited pdf to a file (on a Mac, that's just Print -> pdf -> save as pdf; it's not always quite so easy on other platforms). The process of printing to pdf seems to 'merge' the edits into the file, so that they can't be changed, any they don't disappear under any circumstances.

Comment: In pdf there are different layers for the original file and the comments (if that is what you mean by editing). You need to flatten the file. Don't think it is possible with Foxit Reader, but you can try @IanThompson's trick and just print it with comments. It is not exactly the same but should probably do.